# java media player locked when calling from button click event of a jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I created a panel.Inside that a button called playback.
When I clicked the button then jmf player is playing but in locked condition,
I want all events like stop ,play should work in jmf player.

```
class MediaPanel  extends JPanel{

    public MediaPanel( URL mediaURL ,JDialog media){

      setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
      Manager.setHint( Manager.PLUGIN_PLAYER , true );

        try
          {
            // create a player to play the media specified in the URL
            Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );

            // get the components for the video and the playback controls
            Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

            if ( video != null ) 
               add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER ); // add video component

            if ( controls != null ) 
               add( controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); // add controls

            mediaPlayer.start(); // start playing the media clip
         } 
       catch ( NoPlayerException noPlayerException ){
           noPlayerException.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println( "No media player found" );
       }
       catch ( CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException ){
           cannotRealizeException.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println( "Could not realize media player" );
       }
      catch ( IOException iOException ){
          iOException.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println( "Error reading from the source" );
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: It's likely that `mediaPlayer.start()` is a blocking method, which means it's blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from update the UI or responding to new events.  Try placing the call to `mediaPlayer.start()` in a separate `Thread` or even a `SwingWorker` if you want to easily update the UI....

Comment: Is this using JMF to play the video?  Java-FX, VLCJ..?